# What does "Bad IL Range" exception mean?

Tags: c#, .net

What specifically causes the exception with the message "Bad IL range"?

I've gotten an error report from a customer of mine with this message, but I can't see the exception type. Googling on this text yields very different results, and I suspect this is something pretty low level in .NET/C#, which can occur in many different situations. I assume  IL is "Intermediate Language" in this context.

So what exactly causes this exception, and what may the common underlying reasons for it to happen be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exception type is `BadImageFormatException`, it's thrown when an assembly is corrupted (complete exception message should explain which assembly). There could be many and various reasons for this to happen: viruses, hardware failure, software bugs or a wrong action taken by the user. The exception message and the Fusion log property will contain more information about what kind of error it represents.

You can't do much about that, if the problem persists probably he needs to reinstall your application or .NET Framework, if it did happen just once then he should check for viruses or do a serious hardware test.

Comment: BadImageFormatException can also be thrown when trying to run a x64 assembly in x86 and vice versa.

Comment: @jgauffin right, that exception is thrown for many reasons but it shouldn't report "Bad IL range".

Comment: ehh, then I don't understand your answer?

Comment: :) I just mean that that message is given with that exception (but that exception is not exclusive for that message)

Comment: Ahh. Ok. I thought that you meant that the exception could not be thrown with that message :)

Comment: I would like to mention link to article [System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL Range – what it is going on!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carmelop/archive/2013/06/13/system-badimageformatexception-bad-il-range-what-it-is-going-on.aspx) that describe in more detail for same.

Comment: Just to summarize the link @VikramSaini posted, a possible source for this error can be a faulty obfuscation program. (And that's what I ran into.)

Answer (score 7):

The runtime verifies loaded assemblies and specifically - checks the validity of the supplied CIL - it detects variety of different problems in the CIL structure and the CIL stream.

Although I've never seen this specific problem by myself, I guess the most common reason for this would be the physical corruption of one of application or .NET assemblies.

I would try to reinstall your application (and/or the .NET runtime).

Answer (score 3):

My issue was a dodgy working directory. So a bad DLL somewhere in that, perhaps a nuget reference. Updating all my nuget packages didn't work, solution rebuild didn't work, a pc restart didn't work.

Doing a fresh checkout from my source control (svn) into a new working directory resolved the issue.

I'm on Win10, so there might be something deeper here but I haven't had any further issues for a few days since.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had performed a database migration while `dotnet run` was running. I had to kill that process and restart it and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error occurred because of **disposing an assembly object in event of _FormClosing**, like bellow:

```
if (_kishpos != null)
  _kishpos.Dispose();
```

no need to dispose assembly object's in _FormClosing() event.

**comment or remove it, to fix your "Bad IL range" error.**

```
//if (_kishpos != null)
//  _kishpos.Dispose();
```

my error fixed.

Answer (score 0):

delete the `/bin` and `/obj` folders (for me it was blazor server, vscode, dotnet 7). then run `dotnet run` again.